# Definition of Equals

Tags: definition, symmetry

**DISCLAIMER:** This is a first time Math.SE post from a 30-something who is only now learning math. I have read the Rules and this may not satisfy the "Questions with too many answers" criteria or perhaps this is just too philosophical? ... BUT Mathematical semantics is one of the key things I struggle with in Maths and its almost impossible to google this:

While refreshing my limited knowledge of symmetry I came across this on `themathpage.com`:

> It is not possible to give an explicit definition of the word "equals," or its symbol = . Those rules however are an implicit definition. The meaning of "equals" implies those three rules.

I would have thought `equals` would be easily defined as `identity`. If `a = b` then `a` is `identical` to `b`?

Is not the case in all maths? or is this irrelevant as the page got it wrong.

Comment: The equals sign is a relation i.e it satisfies the reflexive, symmetric, and transitive properties.

Comment: You may find this interesting: http://www.math.harvard.edu/~mazur/preprints/when_is_one.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good mathematical question.

Defining equality by saying it's just identity is not a definition, but rather a reformulation of one undefined term for another undefined term.

We can't define each and everything we use in terms of simpler things since that will result in an infinite descent of concepts. Thus, at some point in the rigorous treatment of anything, we must encounter a term that we simply say is too fundamental to be defined in any simpler terms. At that point we simply adopt the axiomatic approach. Instead of defining what something is, we clearly specify how it behaves. After all, it is the behaviour of things that interests us and not so much what they are composed of. For instance, if there was another chemical compound that exhibited the exact same behaviour as $H_2O$ does, then you would use it just like you use water. You don't care about the atoms composing the molecule, only on the behaviour of the molecule (as long as you are interested in using the chemical for, e.g., drinking).

So, what are the important properties of equality? Well, everything should be equal to itself, so $x=x$ is an axiom. If a bzorkq is equal to a kawataninga then, without caring at all what these things are, we must have that a kawataninga is equal to a bzorkq. Thus we include the axiom $x=y$ implies $y=x$. Finally, I leave it to you to justify the final axiom $x=y$ together with $y=z$ implies $x=z$.

That is what equality is. Equality is not an absolute term and we don't define what it is. Only how it behaves. When two people speak of equality, they implicitly agree that the equality relation they both refer to is the same relation.

Comment: Fantastic thanks so much.

Comment: I somewhat disagrees with your answer. Because it makes it seem as if every equivalence relation is "equality", and while this is part true, the term "equality" has a very unique meaning in the mathematical universe. And equivalent is not necessarily equal. Equality is a primitive notion to mathematics, and we accept that something is only equal to itself. Your answer seem to say "Well, sure, but every two singletons are equal if we only care about their size", and that's not true. Their cardinality is equal but they might not be.

Comment: @AsafKaragila where did I mention cardinality? (and btw, what I quoted here is how Azriel Levy explained equality to us in Logic I). I'm not sure where the disagreement is. I never intended to hint at cardinalities or size of any kind. Equality in maths is taken to be a fixed equivalence relation that is meta-agreed upon. It's intended to perfectly reflect identicalness, but whether it does so is irrelevant.

Comment: You never spoke about cardinality. It's a specific application of what you wrote. That we might not care about two things being actually different, if they serve the same purpose; this is equivalence and not equality. (On a side note, I've had the wonderful pleasure of working with Azriel earlier this year, he's truly special.)

Comment: I still don't see the disagreement then. Equality is a particular meta-choice of a relation. Is it not? Whatever our fantasy about this relation really being just identity is irrelevant and unchechable, so who cares about it?

Comment: Yes, it is a meta-choice of relations. But it is still distinguished from the notion of equivalence relations, because once you made that meta-choice, and you moved to work with it, you can't switch it at will "just like that". Much like what exactly is $0$ and the successor function can be taken to be almost anything, but once you've made your decision there's only one object which is $1$, and that is $S(0)$, regardless to the fact that by changing the choice of $0$ and $S$ will give us different $1$.

Comment: I'm glad to be in agreement with you :)

Comment: You mean that you glad to be right? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Consder the inequality as opposed to the equality.  If I take an inequality and multiply it by -1, the sign "flips" over. $-1(x<y)\rightarrow-x>-y$  But, if we start with an equality, $-1(x=y) \rightarrow -x=-y$.  Did the equal sign flip over?  How would you know? An equality may be seen as a reversible inequality.  Specifically, if $x>y$ and $x<y$, then x and y don't exist, but if $x\geq y$ and $x\leq y$, then x=y.

Answer (score 0):

I somewhat disagree with the text you quoted from that webpage.  Defining what equals "means" just depends on the kind of objects you are considering.  Maybe you take for granted that you know when two natural numbers (i.e., non-negative integers) are equal.  Then two integers $m$ and $n$ are equal if they have the same sign and the natural numbers $|m|$ and $|n|$ are equal.  Two rational numbers $a/b$ and $c/d$ are equal if $ad = bc$.  Real numbers are a bit trickier, but you can define their equality using sequences of rational numbers.

There are lots of other types of mathematical objects besides numbers, too.  For instance, two sets $A$ and $B$ are equal if they contain exactly the same elements.  Two functions $f$ and $g$ are equal if they have the same domain and take on the same value at every point, i.e. $f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x$.  Two (formal) polynomials are equal if all their coefficients are equal.

In the early 1900s, an attempt was made to axiomatize mathematics, meaning people tried to write down a "minimal" list of tacit assumptions upon which the rest of mathematics could be built.  One theory that emerged is called [ZFC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory), and is accepted by many as a "foundation for mathematics" to varying degrees.  In this theory, the set is taken as a "primitive notion," i.e., the thing that we leave undefined.  Amazingly, it is possible to define all mathematical objects in terms of sets.  Thus, if you accept ZFC, all equality comes down to an equality of sets, which as I wrote above, just comes down to checking that two sets have the same elements.